# Using a function inside a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have a view defined for a collection. This view, on render, calls a function that performs certain necessary operations on a Model that is passed in, and appends it to the webpage. Here is a short version of it:

```
addNightFeed: function(nightFeed) {
    var nightFeedView = new app.nightFeedView ({ model: nightFeed });
    this.$el.append(nightFeedView.render().el);
}
```

On my webpage there is an 'Add' button. When clicked, it creates a new Model of the proper type, containing certain attributes.

I was wondering if there is a way to call the addNightFeed on the new Model that is created when 'Add' is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply invoke `viewInstance.addNightFeed(newModalInstance)`. If you can't do that for some reason I can't think of:

Since you have a collection view, you can [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) your collections `add` event and invoke `addNightFeed`. For eg:

```
// Collection view
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addNightFeed);
}
```

When your add button is clicked, you can use the collections [`add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) method to add the already created modal instance to it, or the [`create`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) method to create and add it depending on your requirements. This will trigger `add` event and invoke `addNightFeed`.